# Got error when I type special symbol in input

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

When I type ";/" in search input I will get this error:

> Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: invitees.filter is not a function

Here is my following code in front-end:

```
const { tab, teamId, privateTeamId, fetchTeamData } = props;

  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [invitees, setInvitees] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  const getUserToInvite = async () => {
    const res = await axios.get(
      `/api/v1/search/users/invite/${searchQuery}/${teamId}`
    );
    setInvitees(res.data[0]);
    setShowInvitees(!showInvitees);
  };

          <>
            {invitees
              ?.filter(
                (user) =>
                  user.Memberships.length < 1 ||
                  (user.Memberships.every(
                    (member) => member.teamId !== privateTeamId
                  ) &&
                    user.InvitesApplications.response !== "Waiting on response")
              )
              .sort(
                (a, b) =>
                  new Date(a.InvitesApplications[0]?.createdAt) -
                  new Date(b.InvitesApplications[0]?.createdAt)
              )

           ...
         </>
```

and here is my following code in searchController in back-end:

```
exports.searchUserToInvite = async (req, res) => {
  // Grab query
  const query = req.params.q;

  // Search for users
  const usersFound = await models.User.findAll({
    where: {
      [Op.or]: [
        {
          fullname: {
            [Op.iLike]: query + "%",
          },
        },
      ],
    },
    attributes: [
      "id",
      "fullname",
      "public_user_id",
      "institution",
      "location",
      "webpage",
      "linkedin",
      "major",
      "picture",
      "verifiedDT",
    ],
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Rating,
        attributes: ["skillset_rating", "team_member_rating"],
      },
      {
        model: models.Skill,
        attributes: ["skill"],
      },
      {
        model: models.Membership,
        attributes: ["teamId"],
      },
      {
        model: models.SubMembership,
        attributes: ["subTeamId"],
      },
      {
        model: models.InvitesApplications,
        attributes: [
          "id",
          "response",
          "teamId",
          "subTeamId",
          "createdAt",
          "updatedAt",
        ],
      },
    ],
  });

  // Run searches
  const searchData = await Promise.all([usersFound]);
  // Return results
  if (query.length <= 0) {
    return res.status(200).json([]);
  }
  res.status(200).json(searchData);
};
```

How can I fix this error? Is this because my backend code is wrong or I need to improve my front end code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting your search query as a path parameter seems quite odd but your problem is that you are not encoding the value correctly for use in an URL.

Run the values through [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)...

```js
const res = await axios.get(
  `/api/v1/search/users/invite/${encodeURIComponent(searchQuery)}/${encodeURIComponent(teamId)}`
);
```

---

IMO, search parameters are best handled through query parameters which Axios encodes correctly automatically

```js
const res = await axios.get(url, {
  params: {
    q: searchQuery
  }
})
```

On the server-side, you would read this through `req.query.q`